# (Retention) How to divide all values by value in first row across different categories of users in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

| Day | Category | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | A | 10 |
| D1 | B | 20 |
| D2 | A | 8 |
| D2 | B | 10 |
| D3 | A | 6 |
| D3 | B | 5 |

I'm trying to create a percentage column by dividing the values in the third column (Count) by the value for D1 across all categories in the second column (Category; in this case 10 and 20 for A and B respectively). This should output something like:

| Day | Category | Count | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | A | 10 | 100% |
| D1 | B | 20 | 100% |
| D2 | A | 8 | 80% |
| D2 | B | 10 | 50% |
| D3 | A | 6 | 60% |
| D3 | B | 5 | 25% |

The furthest I got is the code below, but I can't figure out how to do the division by category.

```
    SELECT
        day,
        category,
        count,
        count/(SELECT count FROM table WHERE day = 'D1')*100 AS pct
    FROM 
        table
    ORDER BY 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as Asgar's query but with the unnecessary table derivation removed -

```
SELECT
    `t1`.*,
    ROUND((`t1`.`count` / `t2`.`count`) * 100) `pct`
FROM `table` `t1`
JOIN `table` `t2`
    ON `t1`.`category` = `t2`.`category`
    AND `t2`.`day` = 'D1'
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you ask:

```
SELECT
        day,
        category,
        count,
        count/(SELECT count 
                 FROM table as sub 
                   WHERE day = 'D1' 
                   AND sub.category = main.category)*100 AS pct
    FROM 
        table as main
```

I assumed that the denominator will always just be based on "D1", and that combinations of day-category will always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

This should word accurately for you:

```
SELECT  
main.*,  
ROUND(((main.Count/d2.Count)*100),2) 
FROM
(SELECT *   FROM day_table d1) main
  JOIN day_table d2 ON d2.Category=main.Category AND d2.Day='D1' 
  ORDER BY 
  main.Day, 
  main.Category
```